# Japanese Dog Training Commands

Tags: translation, words

My fiance and I will be moving to Japan sometime next year and are trying to prepare our dog for the experience by teaching her Japanese commands so she can be easily handled by kennels/vets/groomers/etc. What are the most common and useful commands used for dog training in Japan?

I'm betting some are direct translations like "sit," "stay" and "come." But when it comes to things like "go potty" or "drop it" or even "no" (would it just be "ie"?) I'm not sure if there's a more appropriate or universal way to say those. Also if there are any commands that are commonly used in Japan that *aren't* common in America please enlighten me!

Please include romaji in answers for reference because we're still learning to read.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.geocities.jp/talismankatze/dogtopic4.html), starting at 基本的な服従訓練, halfway down the page. All the commands are in hiragana/katakana and you can probably guess the corresponding English command from a machine translation of the explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ote(おて) You show your hand to your dog and say "ote", and the dog our your paw on your hand. I'm not sure the command is common in America, so if you are not sure what is ote, you can watch [this video](https://youtu.be/m5c9-0ygx1A).

Osuwari(おすわり) is also common, which is equivalent to sit.

Fuse(ふせ) is a command for a dog to duck/get down. You can watch [this video](https://youtu.be/R7ud166t50Q) to have idea of fuse. By the way, the spell of romaji "fuse" is equivalent to English word "fuse", but the pronunciation is different. The first word the man say in the video is the correct pronunciation of fuse.

Mate(まて) is almost equivalent to stay. Mate literally means "wait", and it sometimes mean "stay right there", but it sometimes means "wait to eat your food." The pronunciation of "mate" is also very different from English word mate. The second word the man say in [this video](https://youtu.be/R7ud166t50Q) is the correct pronunciation of mate.

Oide(おいで) is equivalent to "come".

Chodai(ちょうだい) is equivalent to "drop it".

Mottekoi(もってこい) is equivalent to "go fetch".

Dame(だめ) and Ikenai(いけない) is equivalent to "no", "ie" is not common to tell a dog you are doing wrong thing.

I've never heard a Japanese person command a dog "go potty". I don't think the command is common in Japan.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, that's exactly what I was looking for! It looks like "ote" would be most similar to "paw" or "high-five" though the gesture is a bit different from a typical "high-five." It basically looks like an obedience training trick.