# More dog training commands

Tags: translation

I found this answer:

[Japanese Dog Training Commands](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25155/japanese-dog-training-commands)

For most dog training commands, but I didn't see anything for "stand" or "stay"

I think that "stay" would be まて but I couldn't quite figure that out.

I also learned something like "ikky mah sho" (english phonetics) for "Let's go" - but it was a long time ago (before the internet was born!) and I don't have any clue where it came from or if it is even remotely correct.

Any help?

Comment: I have nothing to say about dog commands.  I can say that your _"ikky mah sho"_ is 行きましょう (_ikimashō_), the polite form (the _mas_ part) of the optative conjugation (i.e. "let's do", the _ō_ on the end) of the root verb 行く (_iku_, "to go").  Hope that helps some!

Comment: Why the downvote, when the previous question that this continues on was upvoted?  Yeesh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Stand (from the down/sit position)" is 立て【たて】, but this is probably less common as compared to おすわり/すわれ/ふせ.

"Stay" is まて, you can find this in the answer you linked. There is also おあずけ, which is "Wait (to eat)" and specifically used in front of a meal.

"Ikky mah sho" should be 行きましょう, which is "Let's go" in English, but I don't think it's a dog command.

Related: [Why are dogs asked to 「おすわり」 instead of 「すわれ」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55697/5010)